# Why does PyCharm complain that `Expected type 'Tag', got 'str' instead`?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I have defined a variable `offer` which has the type of `bs4.element.Tag`. I have also defined a function `get_price` which scrapes the price from this tag and returns it as a string. When I run the following code:

```
def get_price(row: bs4.element.Tag) -> str:
    wrapper = row.find('td', class_='item_price')
    price = wrapper.find('span', class_='price')

    try:
        price_stripped = price.text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        price_stripped = ''

    return price_stripped

print(type(row))
print(get_price(row))
```

I get

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
€25.00
```

which is the output I expected. However, why does PyCharm complain that `Expected type 'Tag', got 'str' instead` at the last line of my code? I'm confused as I believe I passed an object of type 'Tag' to `get_price`, so it doesn't make sense to me why PyCharm 'thinks' I passed it an object of type `str`.